# Can't text-align:center on css

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my "Home" buttons to the center. The home text is at the left instead of the center.I have my htm and css linked like this:
html:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="background.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Bully-Free Zone</h1>
  <h2>"Online harassment has an off-line impact"</h2>
  <a href="New.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Css:

```
a.nav-link:link
{
color: black;
text-decoration: underline;
font-family:broadway;
font-size:30px;
text-align:center;
}
a.nav-link:visited
{
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:hover
{
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:active
{
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could wrap it in a `div`:

```
<div align="center">
  <a href="New.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
</div>
```

Or you can create a class for the `div`:

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv">
  <a href="New.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: If you're happy with the solution, could you click the Check Icon next to the answer?

Comment: Which one is more professional?
Using only html inline text?
or creating a css class?

Comment: It's really up to you. It's always a lot cleaner to create the class in CSS, and makes it easier to change the attributes if say one moment you decide you'd like to add a border, background-color, and padding. And if you wanted to add more links for example or similar links, you'd only need to reference the same class rather than typing it out in html all over again.

Answer (score 2):

The text-align property will only center the text within the container it's in. In this case, the a tag is only as wide as the text. So regardless how you set your text-align property on that link tag, it will always appear the same. To center it you need to put it in an element that is wider.

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="New.html" class="nav-link>Home</a>
</div>
```

and your css:

```
#nav
{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Property text-align:center should be appurtenant to parent element

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">Link</a>

a {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reply 8 months late but I had the same problem as Backtrack and by trying a combination of the above answers I managed to fix my mishap this way. I share it very respectfully with you, in case someone needs this solution in the future.

CSS:

```css
a {

  text-align: center;

  margin: 20px;

  display: block;

   }
```

It also works if you use an "Id" in the "a" tag.