# text-align: center not working on <a> but does on <h1>

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple and straight forward form:

```
<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <input class="input" type="text" name="_username" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}"
           value="{{ last_username }}" required />
    <input class="input" type="password" name="_password"
           placeholder="{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}" required />
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label class="text" for="remember_me">
        {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}
    </label>
    {% if error %}
        <div class="err">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    <button>{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}</button>
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}">Forgot your password?</a>
</form>
```

My CSS:

```
form {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    padding: 45px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

form h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}

form h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}

form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"] {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}

form input[type="checkbox"] {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    outline: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
}

form .text {
    color: #919191;
    font-size: 14px;
}

form a {
    color: #919191;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

My text-align: center works perfectly on `<h1>`, but why doesn't it work for my `<a>` link? I don't get it. Can someone please help, or explain why? It is not as if something is really complex with this simple design.

Comment: try this <center><a href="">Forgot your password?</a></center>

Comment: @BilalAhmed The `<center>` element is obsolete as of HTML5.

Comment: <div style="text-align: center;"><a href="">link</a>

Comment: try this... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align:center` applies to the content of the tag.

`h1` is a block element, thus occupying the entire width. and that is why the content within it can be centered.

`a` is an inline element, the width is only what is contained within the tag, that is why it can't be centered.

You can either wrap the `a` with a block element

`<div> <a></a> </div>`

or give it a `display:block`

Answer (score 2):

Your text most likely does center, but an anchor is an inline element and therefore has the width of its content. 
Try this (adding: display:block):

```
form a {
   color: #919191;
   font-size: 14px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   display:block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  a{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Can't text-align:center on css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183800/cant-text-aligncenter-on-css)

You could wrap it in a div:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete as of HTML5.